# Custom Model Mass Importer

Tags: module, magento-1, model, csv

I built a module that has a custom Model and database table it includes an admin backend model manager which allows me to export the data to a CSV/Excel file.

What is the best way to go ahead and add the feature of importing data from a CSV file.

Comment: Are you asking the best way to import data like you are exporting data? Like an opinion?

Comment: no, i'm wondering how do i go about doing this, since the backend model manager doesn't come with this functionality by default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always create custom dataflow adapters (even for non-custom models like products or customers). It's very flexible and you don't have to deal with all the io stuff and batching/timeouts.

Create a class that extends `Mage_Dataflow_Model_Convert_Adapter_Abstract` or `Mage_Eav_Model_Convert_Adapter_Entity` if you have an EAV model.

Implement the required methods (specifically `saveRow($row)`)

Add your advanced dataflow profile in the admin panel:

```
<action type="dataflow/convert_adapter_io" method="load">
    <var name="type">file</var>
    <var name="path">var/import</var>
    <var name="filename"><![CDATA[my-csv.csv]]></var>
</action>
<action type="dataflow/convert_parser_csv" method="parse">
    <var name="delimiter"><![CDATA[,]]></var>
    <var name="enclose"><![CDATA["]]></var>
    <var name="fieldnames">true</var>
    <var name="store"><![CDATA[0]]></var>
    <var name="number_of_records">1</var>
    <var name="decimal_separator"><![CDATA[.]]></var>
    <var name="adapter">my_company/convert_adapter_mycustommodel</var>
    <var name="method">parse</var>
</action>
```

That should be a good high-level overview. Dataflow can be confusing sometimes though.